Can you get an atom to “orbit” another?
If you had a binary molecule with one atom in the molecule much heavier than the other moving quickly through some sort of magnetic field setup, could you get one of the atoms to “orbit” the other due to the difference in their trajectories due to the difference in mass of each atom? The atoms would still be bonded but each would act differently under the magnetic field leading to one rotating around the other.

Wouldn't that just be a rotating molecule? e.g. take an HI molecule where the hydrogen atom is $\tfrac{1}{127}$ of the mass of the iodine atom. The centre of mass will be virtually at the iodine nucleus so when this molecule rotates it will look as if the hydrogen is orbiting the iodine.

@JohnRennie Opposite charges in a magnetic field rotate in opposite directions. If the bond was purely electrostatic between ions (not atoms) then the answer wouldn't be so obvious.

"the difference in their trajectories" Do you want to ask about the possibility of breaking the tidal locking between the two nuclei, using the magnetic field?

"The atoms would still be bonded but each would act differently under the magnetic field leading to one rotating around the other" - this sounds rather like magnetic resonance - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_(quantum_mechanics) .

@gandalf61 Rather https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy

It seems to me that the word 'orbiting' has a connotation of referring to motion under the influence of a force that is attracting only.
While it is the case that a diatomic molecule can be in a state of high rotational kinetic energy, I argue that the word 'orbiting' should not be used to refer to that motion.
Generally, when rotational kinetic energy is high the vibrational mode of the molecule will also be in a high energy state. A diatomic molecule has a vibrational mode because on close approach of the atoms there is a repulsive effect. The vibrational mode is an oscillation relative to the molecule's atom-atom distance that has the lowest molecular energy.
(Incidentally, rotational mode and vibrational mode tend to interact; that phenomenon is referred to as 'rotational-vibrational coupling'.)
So:
I submit it's not a good idea to extend usage of the word 'orbiting' to cover the case of a diatomic molecule with high rotational kinetic energy. Nothing is gained by that.

Other than that: it's not clear why you mention 'some sort of magnetic field setup'.
It could be that what you have in mind is motion of a charged particle (or charged molecule) in a cyclotron. Yes, in a cyclotron the magnetic field causes charged particles to go around, but in that case the force that pulls the particle into curvilinear motion is an external influence. That is not one atom orbiting another atom.

In principle there is nothing stopping it. In practice, the binding would be too weak. Consider two carbon atoms at $r=10^{-10}$ m and $M=2\cdot 10^{-26}$ kg, we get a gravitational potential energy energy $GM/r$ around $1.3348\cdot 10^{-15}$ J/kg. But that means a total energy on the order of $2.6696\cdot 10^{-41}$ J, way lower than the translational energy of atoms at picokelvin temperatures. The atoms would bump into stuff with far more kinetic energy and get dislodged.

Why consider only gravitational force? There is also Van der Waals force and (in case of ionized atoms) coulombic attraction.

@PaulKolk - Because the question was about gravitational attraction due to mass (albeit confusing the issue by then introducing a magnetic field).

The question mentions atoms in a molecule. So, bound already. It doesn't mention gravitation. Maybe inertia from mass???  I agree, it's confusing. Answering a confusing question adds more confusion.

@PaulKolk - Ah, the question was repeatedly changed into different questions. My answer refers to how it looked yesterday, when no molecule or magnetic field was mentioned.
